# React-Native Redux pass data from component to store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am actually new in redux, I started to discover it and understand its logic. I have a question in my mind that, is it possible to make api calls inside of components and pass the responses to store?

Because as I understand we can make API calls by triggering actions with action creators, but can I do make calls in component and when I get results am I able to pass it to reducer and store without using action creators?

How its possible, can someone give me a small example of it, if my question is logical?

Comment: *without using action creators* - you mean without **actions**? The whole point of Redux is that you dispatch an action with its payload and then store handles it as needed. Without using actions you could easily lose control of your store as you use async operations like API calls

Comment: You can make your API call inside your component, and use action and reducer for just passing the result. That's possible even if not the best practice. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes @FarukYazıcı. Why its not the best practice, whats different if API call happens inside of component or in action component? 

Can you give me an example how I could do that